# Partial derivative of an Integral - potentially trivial

Tags: calculus, probability-theory, random-variables

The following is from my lecture notes:

> Given
>   $$C(K) = \int^{\infty}_K(x-K)\rho(x)dx$$ where $\rho$ is a density function.
>   It is trivial to show that
>   $$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial K^2}C(K) = \rho(K)$$

I don't understand how it is possible to go from the first line to the second. Is it trivial? If not could someone give me a hint at how to proceed.

Comment: You should see the Leibniz integral rule for instance at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$C(K)=\int_K^{\infty} x\rho (x)dx-K \int_K^{\infty} \rho(x)dx$. So the first derivative w.r.t. $K$ is $-K\rho (K)-\int_K^{\infty} \rho(x)dx+K\rho (K)=-\int_K^{\infty} \rho(x)dx$ (where we have used the product rule). Hence the  second derivative is $\rho (K)$.

Comment: I am just using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.